# JQuery add items to my JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm making a little game with phonegap and this is my code for local storage/scoreboard. I keep the score with the time in this scoreboard, i made a couple of exmples and they show up, but not the ones i'm supposed to add?

```
var localData = function(){

var _local = [
    {
        "score": 1,
        "datum": "di 25 jan 2016"
    },
    {
        "score": 5,
        "datum": "di 26 jan 2016"
    },
    {
        "score": 9,
        "datum": "di 27 jan 2016"
    },
    {
        "score": 10,
        "datum": "di 28 jan 2016"
    }
];


var _setLocalStorage = function () {
    console.log("Score word bewaard");
    console.log(_local);
    localStorage.setItem('LocalData', JSON.stringify(_local));
    _scoreList();
};

var _scoreList = function () {
    var DatumVanNu =  new Date().toDateString();
    console.log(DatumVanNu + ' _local = ' + _local.length);
    console.log(_local);
    $('#tbodyid').empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < _local.length; i++){
        console.log(_local[i].datum)

        var item = '<tr> <td>' + _local[i].score + '</td> <td>'+ _local[i].datum +'</td> </tr>';
         $('tbody').append(item);

    }
    console.log('gedaan')
};

var init = function () {
    console.log("score word geopent");
    _local = [];
    var local_str = localStorage.getItem('LocalData');
    if(local_str !== null){
        _local = JSON.parse(local_str);
    }
    console.log(_local);
    _scoreList();

};
var addScore = function (score) {
    console.log("Score wordt toegevoegd");
    var datum = new Date();
    _local.score = score;
    _local.datum = datum;
    _scoreList();

};

return {
    init:   init,
    addScore:  addScore
};

}()
```

Comment: `_local.push(obj)`? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Why the close vote?? This is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are adding properties to your `_local` list instead of adding an item to it in function `addScore`

Try changing to the following

```
var addScore = function (score) {
    _local.push({score: score, datum : new Date()});
    _scoreList();
};
```

Instead of

```
  _local = []
  ... 
  _local.score = .. 
  _local.datanum = ...
```

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

you need to push, as its an array:

```
var addScore = function (score) {
console.log("Score wordt toegevoegd");
var datum = new Date();
  elem={};
  elem.score = score;
  elem.datum = datum;
  _local.push(elem);
 _scoreList();
};
```